# How to not clip child views when using outline provider

Tags: android

I am using an outline provider to create rounded corners on a view and than apply some elevation to create the card effect:

```
setClipToOutline(true);
setOutlineProvider(new ViewOutlineProvider() {
  @Override
  public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
    outline.setRoundRect(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), cardCornerRadius);
  }
});
```

The problem with the outline provider (and the accompanying `setClipToOutline(true)`) is that while it clips the background of the view it also clips the child views. I would like to draw children outside of the view to animate removal of content.

Therefore my question is: How can i only provide the outline for the background and the elevation and not clip the children with the outline?

Comment: there're two related methods `View.setClipToOutline(boolean)` and `ViewGroup.setClipChildren(boolean);`. Did you try them?? **EDIT** I just saw your code. You probably should call `clipToOutline(false)` if you don't want to clip children

Comment: @Budius Yes i tried the combination of the two flags but the outline seams to have precedence. Also i need to `clipToOutline` to be true in order to get the rounded corners from the background drawable.